# FluentAssertions: collection subset should contain equivalent of list

Tags: fluent-assertions

I have a collection:

```
new[] { new { A = 5, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" }, new { A = 7, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" }, new { A = 9, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" } }
```

I want to check that it at least contains both `new { A = 9 }` and `new { A = 5 }` in any order.

I can use `ContainEquivalentOf`, but I have to do it one-by-one:

```
var actual = new[] { 
  new { A = 5, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" }, 
  new { A = 7, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" }, 
  new { A = 9, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" } 
};
var expected = new [] { new { A = 5 }, new { A = 9 } };
foreach (var expectedItem in expected) {
    actual.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(expectedItem);
}
```

Update: I can't use `Contains` because it requires actual and expected objects to have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see an explicit solution. You can work-around using `Select` to create subject in the format of the expectation, then you can use
`Contains(IEnumerable<T> expected, ...)`:

```cs
var actual = new[] { 
    new { A = 1, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" }, 
    new { A = 7, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" }, 
    new { A = 9, PropIDontCareAbout = "XXX" } 
};

actual.Select(x => new { x.A }).Should()
    .Contain(new[] { new { A = 9 }, new { A = 5 } });
```

In case of one the elements is not in the list you get a message like that:

```
Expected collection {{ A = 1 }, { A = 7 }, { A = 9 }}
to contain {{ A = 9 }, { A = 5 }},
but could not find {{ A = 5 }}.
```

Comment: @thx-1138, would be great to get feedback for my answer!

Comment: apologies for the late response. Your solution does not work because `Contain` does an exact match while I need `Equivalent` comparison that does partial object matching. I will update my question.

Comment: You are right, @THX-1138. I've updated my answer with a work-around.